# Magento 2.0 / 2.X Mutli Language

Tags: magento2

can anyone explain how does the magento 2.0 language works?

For 1.X, its a language pack to install but in 2.0 it seems everything is different. Would any one please show me a direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2 also language pack available, you can see here "vendor/magento/language-es_es" ,"language-fr_fr".

And if you want to create you can also create you have to put your language pack file "app/i18n/vendor name/hu_hu/".

For more detail you can check here :http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Comment: So there's no package that I can download? I basically have to translate everything myself?

Comment: All language pack are not ready  at but some you can found from here:
https://bitbucket.org/etws/m2_russianlanguagepack/src,
https://github.com/lalbert/magento2-fr_fr,
https://github.com/wojtekn/magento2-language-pl,
https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2

Answer (score 0):

Seems Magento 2 doesn't have standard language packs out yet.

They do have a dictionary generation tool, however, I don't know how useful it is.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html#m2devgde-xlate-dictionaries

Good Luck.